# linking problems with glfw static libraries

Tags: c++, eclipse, mingw, glfw

I am trying to link these [GLFW](http://www.glfw.org/download.html) static libraries to my c++ project with eclipse:

- libglfw3.a
- libglfw3dll.a

But eclipse throws this error: [image: Linking Error]
From what I can tell, it seems to find them just fine. However, the linking error says that the libraries are incompatible. I am using **mingw 64-bit** to compile so it would make sense that I use the 64-bit version of the [GLFW](http://www.glfw.org/download.html) that came with the .zip file. But even then, I tried linking it with the 32-bit version of [GLFW](http://www.glfw.org/download.html) and it still throws the same error. Does anyone know why it is doing this?

Just in case, this is how I build the file:

*g++ "-LE:\Extra\8) Programs\Files\GLFW\lib-mingw-w64" -o OpenGL.exe "src\Main.o" -lglfw3 -lglfw3dll*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One quick way would be to include the full path of the library files.

- And link either the static or the shared library. Not both of them.
- If the full path works, then the path variables may not be set properly